# Undetectable hypervisor for malware analysis

Tags: security, virtualization, malware

I am looking for a hypervisor that can be "hidden" from the guest OS such that they believe that they are running on real hardware, instead of being virtualized.

Microsoft-VM's report the motherboard as made by "Microsoft Corporation" - and since they don't actually make motherboards, this is a giveaway

VMware forces the NIC MAC address to fit the following format: "00:50:56:XX:YY:ZZ" which is detectable.

Is there any hypervisor that has no such flaws, or can be configured to hide them from the guest OS?

I realize that any hyper-visor is subject to a timing attack, however I would like something that does better than provide "plug-in-hooks" for compatibility - as for the purpose, I am looking to dissect a virus in a "safe" environment, but notice that it isn't acting as expected in a virtualized environment.

Comment: Have you considered using Xen, which is open source and therefore you can modify any detail you like?

Comment: @GregHewgill - not sure I know where to look through the code for "giveaways" (there are quite a few), but I suppose I could try if there aren't any other alternatives that are pre-configured for such a task

Comment: I'm not sure that what you want is really possible - even if it doesn't have something as obvious as the device names, almost every hypervisor is going to end up having various 'tells' that are a result of it's implementation.

Comment: @MichaelKohne - I agree, however whoever made the virus is also unlikely to check for every single "tell" in every single hypervisor, and I am somewhat surprised that there doesn't seem to be any that exists already for this purpose, or a configurable setting.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that this _has_ been solved before, but people who did solve it saw no reason to publish their changes.